# How to return only certain fields using get_posts()

Tags: plugin-development, get-posts

I'm trying to get only the fields that I need using the `get_posts()` function in WordPress. I currently have the following code:

```
    $posts_args = array(
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    );

    $post_ids_r = get_posts($posts_args);
```

This works fine if I only want to get the id. But if I want to get the permalink or the title of the post along with the ids that's where I'm not sure what to do. I already tried the following:

```
'fields' => array('ids', 'post_titles')
'fields' => 'ids,post_titles'
'fields' => 'ids,titles'
'fields' => array('ids','titles')
```

But nothing works, I guess the only one that it recognizes is the `ids` field. Is there any other way to do this if its really not possible to do it using `get_posts()`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`get_posts` passes the heavy lifting off to `WP_Query`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post.php#L1723) and if you look at the source of that class you can see that there are only a [limited number of options with that `fields` argument](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/query.php#L2034). There are only three options in that `switch`-- `ids`, `id=>parent`, and the default case, everything.

You can use the `posts_fields` filter to alter what fields get returned, though [it looks like you need to pass `'suppress_filters => false` in the arguments in order to get that filter to run](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post.php#L1703). It should look something like this:

```
function alter_fields_wpse_108288($fields) {
  return 'ID,post_title'; // etc
}
add_filter('posts_fields','alter_fields_wpse_10888');
```

However, there is a larger problem. The post objects that get returned are created by a call to [`get_post`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/query.php#L2679) and [it doesn't honor the values passed into the original query](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post.php#L386) and I don't see a way to change what gets returned either in `get_posts` or in the [`WP_Post` class itself](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post.php#L424).

Comment: It seems like the `'fields'` parameter has been introduced in a 5.x version of WP. Just doing `get_posts(array('fields' => 'ids'))` would get posts with just the post ids without doing the `posts_fields` filter. Please correct me if I am wrong, because it worked for me in the latest wp version (5.2.4) without adding the filter. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Have a look to this

```
function get_posts_fields( $args = array() ) {
  $valid_fields = array(
    'ID'=>'%d', 'post_author'=>'%d',
    'post_type'=>'%s', 'post_mime_type'=>'%s',
    'post_title'=>false, 'post_name'=>'%s', 
    'post_date'=>'%s', 'post_modified'=>'%s',
    'menu_order'=>'%d', 'post_parent'=>'%d', 
    'post_excerpt'=>false, 'post_content'=>false,
    'post_status'=>'%s', 'comment_status'=>false, 'ping_status'=>false,
    'to_ping'=>false, 'pinged'=>false, 'comment_count'=>'%d'
  );
  $defaults = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
  );
  global $wpdb;
  $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);
  $where = "";
  foreach ( $valid_fields as $field => $can_query ) {
    if ( isset($args[$field]) && $can_query ) {
      if ( $where != "" )  $where .= " AND ";
      $where .= $wpdb->prepare( $field . " = " . $can_query, $args[$field] );
    }
  }
  if ( isset($args['search']) && is_string($args['search']) ) {
      if ( $where != "" )  $where .= " AND ";
      $where .= $wpdb->prepare("post_title LIKE %s", "%" . $args['search'] . "%");
  }
  if ( isset($args['include']) ) {
     if ( is_string($args['include']) ) $args['include'] = explode(',', $args['include']); 
     if ( is_array($args['include']) ) {
      $args['include'] = array_map('intval', $args['include']); 
      if ( $where != "" )  $where .= " OR ";
      $where .= "ID IN (" . implode(',', $args['include'] ). ")";
    }
  }
  if ( isset($args['exclude']) ) {
     if ( is_string($args['exclude']) ) $args['exclude'] = explode(',', $args['exclude']); 
     if ( is_array($args['exclude']) ) {
      $args['exclude'] = array_map('intval', $args['exclude']);
      if ( $where != "" ) $where .= " AND "; 
      $where .= "ID NOT IN (" . implode(',', $args['exclude'] ). ")";
    }
  }
  extract($args);
  $iscol = false;
  if ( isset($fields) ) { 
    if ( is_string($fields) ) $fields = explode(',', $fields);
    if ( is_array($fields) ) {
      $fields = array_intersect($fields, array_keys($valid_fields)); 
      if( count($fields) == 1 ) $iscol = true;
      $fields = implode(',', $fields);
    }
  }
  if ( empty($fields) ) $fields = '*';
  if ( ! in_array($orderby, $valid_fields) ) $orderby = 'post_date';
  if ( ! in_array( strtoupper($order), array('ASC','DESC')) ) $order = 'DESC';
  if ( ! intval($posts_per_page) && $posts_per_page != -1)
     $posts_per_page = $defaults['posts_per_page'];
  if ( $where == "" ) $where = "1";
  $q = "SELECT $fields FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE " . $where;
  $q .= " ORDER BY $orderby $order";
  if ( $posts_per_page != -1) $q .= " LIMIT $posts_per_page";
  return $iscol ? $wpdb->get_col($q) : $wpdb->get_results($q);
}
```

It's a function that *mimics* get_posts but with the ability to get the fields you desire. Be aware: this function is **not** get_posts and has 2 great limitations: run only in posts table so taxonomy and meta query cannot be run!

However, the query can rely on all the post fields and on some 'special' arguments like `include`, `exclude` and `search`.

The good part is this: the fields you are able to retrieve are **all** the field of the post table. Just pass a list or an array in the `fields` argument.
Bonus: passing only one field is returned a one dimensional array of strings or integers (instead of an array of objects).

### List of Available args are:

```
$available_args = array(
  'ID', // int
  'post_author', // string
  'post_type', // string
  'post_mime_type', // string
  'post_name', // string
  'post_date', // string
  'post_modified', // string
  'menu_order', // int
  'post_parent', // int 
  'post_status', // string
  'comment_status', // string
  'comment_count', // int 
  'orderby', // string, a valid field name
  'order', // string 'ASC', or 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page', // int
  'include', // array (or comma separed string) of post ids
  'exclude', // array (or comma separed string) of post ids
  'search', // string if passed will search for it in post title
  'fields', // array (or comma separed string) of fields to retrieve.
            // If only 1 field is passed a 'flat' array is returned 
);
```

### Examples of usage

```
// Retrieve the date and the title of pages having 'Hello' in the title
$pages_hello = get_posts_fields("post_type=page&search=Hello&fields=post_date,post_title");


// another example
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'custom_post',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_parent' => 1,
  'include' => array(2,3,4),
  'exclude' => '6,8,10',
  'fields' => array('post_title', 'comment_status')
);
get_posts_fields($args);


// One more, just for fun ;)
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'inherit', 'fields' => 'post_mime_type'
);
foreach ( array_count_values ( get_posts_fields($args) ) as $mime => $count ) {
  echo "I have $count media of the type $mime" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `'ids'` or `'id=>parent'` for the parameter `fields`.

If you parse something else it will return all fields (this is default).

However, it would be nice if Wordpress could add the following 2 options: `'titles'` and `'ids_and_titles'`.

I am not aware of a way to parse an array for this parameter. I also think it will never happen, since the limits of the answer given by G. M.

More info:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Return_Fields_Parameter

Comment: `id=>parent` is no valid argument.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, you can do this with the WP Rest API using the _fields parameter

```
https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=author,id,excerpt,title,link
```

More info on the API here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks gmazzap for that function!
I was looking for a solution to get some custom fields in one with the get_posts, so I felt free to extend it for custom fields of the postmeta table:

```
function get_posts_fields($args = array())
{
    $valid_fields = array(
        'ID' => '%d',
        'post_author' => '%d',
        'post_type' => '%s',
        'post_mime_type' => '%s',
        'post_title' => false,
        'post_name' => '%s',
        'post_date' => '%s',
        'post_modified' => '%s',
        'menu_order' => '%d',
        'post_parent' => '%d',
        'post_excerpt' => false,
        'post_content' => false,
        'post_status' => '%s',
        'comment_status' => false,
        'ping_status' => false,
        'to_ping' => false,
        'pinged' => false,
        'comment_count' => '%d',
        'custom_fields' => false,
    );

    $defaults = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page')
    );

    global $wpdb;

    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);
    $where = "";
    $meta = "";
    $groupBy = "";

    foreach ($valid_fields as $field => $can_query) {
        if (isset($args[$field]) && $can_query) {
            if ($where != "") {
                $where .= " AND ";
            }
            $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
                $wpdb->posts.".".$field . " = " . $can_query,
                $args[$field]
            );
        }
    }

    if (isset($args['search']) && is_string($args['search'])) {
        if ($where != "") {
            $where .= " AND ";
        }
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
            "post_title LIKE %s",
            "%" . $args['search'] . "%"
        );
    }

    if (isset($args['include'])) {
        if (is_string($args['include'])) {
            $args['include'] = explode(',', $args['include']);
        }
        if (is_array($args['include'])) {
            $args['include'] = array_map('intval', $args['include']);
            if ($where != "") {
                $where .= " OR ";
            }
            $where .= $wpdb->posts.".ID IN (" . implode(',', $args['include']) . ")";
        }
    }

    if (isset($args['exclude'])) {
        if (is_string($args['exclude'])) {
            $args['exclude'] = explode(',', $args['exclude']);
        }
        if (is_array($args['exclude'])) {
            $args['exclude'] = array_map('intval', $args['exclude']);
            if ($where != "") {
                $where .= " AND ";
            }
            $where .= $wpdb->posts.".ID NOT IN (" . implode(',', $args['exclude']) . ")";
        }
    }




    extract($args);
    $iscol = false;
    if (isset($fields)) {
        if (is_string($fields)) {
            $fields = explode(',', $fields);
        }
        if (is_array($fields)) {
            $fields = array_intersect($fields, array_keys($valid_fields));
            if (count($fields) == 1) {
                $iscol = true;
            }

            for($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {
              $fields[$i] = "$wpdb->posts.$fields[$i]";
            }

        }
    }

    if (isset($args['custom_fields'])) {
      if (is_string($args['custom_fields'])) {
            $args['custom_fields'] = explode(',', $args['custom_fields']);
      }


      if (is_array($args['custom_fields'])) {
          foreach( $args['custom_fields'] as $custom_field) {
            $fields[] =  "MAX(CASE WHEN df_postmeta.meta_key = '$custom_field' then df_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as $custom_field";
          }
          $meta = " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ( $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID)";
          $groupBy = " GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_title";
        }
    }

    if (empty($fields)) {
        $fields = '*';
    } else {
      $fields = implode(',', $fields);
    }



    if( in_array($orderby, $valid_fields) ) {
      $orderby = $wpdb->posts.'.'.$orderby;
    }else if( isset( $args['custom_fields']) && in_array($orderby, $args['custom_fields']) ) {
      $orderby = $orderby;
    } else {
      $orderby = $wpdb->posts.'.post_date';
    }


    if (!in_array(strtoupper($order), array('ASC', 'DESC'))) {
        $order = 'DESC';
    }

    if (!intval($posts_per_page) && $posts_per_page != -1) {
        $posts_per_page = $defaults['posts_per_page'];
    }

    if ($where == "") {
        $where = "1";
    }



    $q = "SELECT $fields FROM $wpdb->posts " . $meta . " WHERE " . $where;
    $q .= $groupBy;
    $q .= " ORDER BY $orderby $order";

    if ($posts_per_page != -1) {
        $q .= " LIMIT $posts_per_page";
    }

    print $q;

    return $iscol ? $wpdb->get_col($q) : $wpdb->get_results($q);
}
```

You can use the orderby of that fields too.
A small example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => array('ID', 'post_title'),
    'orderby' => 'project_clients',
    'order' => 'DESC',

    'custom_fields' => array(
        'project_clients',
        'project_dop'
     ),
);
$projects = get_posts_fields($args);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display the post title inside a template or in a plugin, you can use:

```
get_the_title($ID)
```

See wordpress reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

If you're using it outside the loop, the $ID is required.
Either way, it will probably be used like this:

You can also use:

the_permalink() - to retrieve post permalink
the_title() - to retrieve post title

These are all wordpress template tags. A full list of template tags you can use are found here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags

Comment: How does this answer the question?